# Runtime Error in VBA 3075

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime

I am trying to create a search form in Access where in people can search records by date range. But each time I click search I get a run time error 3075... with `DoCmd.ApplyFilter` task highlighted. I am new to VBA.

```
Private Sub Command62_Click()
    ' Search Button
    Call Search
End Sub
```

```
Sub Search()

    Dim strCriteria, task As String

    Me.Refresh
    If IsNull(Me.txtDateIntakeAssignedFrom) Or IsNull(Me.txtDateIntakeAssignedTo) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the date range", vbInformation, "Date Range Required"
        Me.txtDateIntakeAssignedFrom.SetFocus
    Else
        strCriteria = "([Date_Staff_Assigned]) >= #" & Me.txtDateIntakeAssignedFrom & "# And [Date_Staff_Assigned] <= #" & Me.txtDateIntakeAssignedTo & "#)"
        task = "select * from frmCustomizeSearchDataonDatasheet where (" & strCriteria & ") order by [Date_Staff_Assigned]"
        DoCmd.ApplyFilter task
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your question. See here for help https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I believe ApplyFilter only requires the search criteria - not the whole SQL clause - just try using 'DoCmd.ApplyFilter strCriteria'